# Использование Toolbar от разных фрагментов в MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть реализация разных Toolbar в разных фрагментах. Например,

**Fragment1.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //Действия с Toolbar'ом...
    return v;
}
```

В MainActivity есть реализация NavigationDrawer с меню для переключения между фрагментами. Там есть строка:

**MainActivity.java**

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

В третьем аргументе необходимо указать Toolbar для того, чтобы слева сделать "гамбургер" для открытия NavigationDrawer. Не подскажете, как это реализовать при разных Toolbar'ах в разных фрагментах?

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос

Comment: @McDaggen Смотрите: к каждому фрагменту присоединен Toolbar (они все разные), к Activity присоединены все эти фрагменты и NavigationDrawer. Его можно открыть, потянув экран справа или нажав на гамбургер, то есть mDrawerToggle. В третьем аргументе этого конструктора нужно указать Toolbar, но он для каждого фрагмента разный, поэтому этот аргумент меняется в зависимости от открытого фрагмента. Как передать Toolbar от любого из фрагментов к этому конструктору?

Comment: Не легче ли вам менять данные в тулбаре с переключением фрагмента, нежели менять весь тулбар? Что конкретно меняется в вашем тулбаре? Заглавление, может добавляется в пункты меню новый пункт?

Comment: Получите доступ к главному тулбару из фрагмента, и в каждом нужном  фрагменте реализуйте смену содержимого этого тулбара, заглавление, пункты меню и прочее, и с загрузкой фрагментов основной тулбар будет заполнен из фрагментов, и вам не потребуется передавать в конструктор нужный тулбар.

Comment: @McDaggen Большое спасибо! Попробую это реализовать, наверное, это можно сделать через MainActivity.getToolbar? Если да, то тогда понятно. Я тут недавно, но, по-моему, Ваш пост нужно оформить как ответ, чтобы я Вам смог поднять репутацию...

Comment: @McDaggen В принципе, меняется только заголовок, цвет Toolbar'a и пункты меню. В общем, мелочи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам следует:

- Создать один `BaseActivity` как Базовый.
- И в `Toolbar` этого `ActiVYty`добавить иконку "Гамбургер" с Меню
- В разметке `BaseActivity` добавить `Frame Layout`, в этом случае ваш 
  "гамбургер" появится во фрагментах
- И при нажатии на пункт меню будут меняться контент, но `Toolbar` останется неизменным

Надеюсь поняли суть...

**UPD:**

Во фрагментах к `Toolbar`'у `Activity` можете подключаться и менять таким образом:

```
//Менять заголовок
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();

//Менять цвет `Toolbar`
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable();
```

А для работы с пунктами меню, необходимо будет переопределить метод `onOptionsItemSelected()`

и добавить `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` в методе `onCreate()`

Comment: Это уже сделано, но мне как раз нужно обратное действие: у каждого фрагмента есть свой Toolbar, причем у всех есть "гамбургер", который должен присоединяться к аргументу конструктора в Activity. Как передать "гамбургер" от фрагмента к Activity? Или как-то можно менять Toolbar в процессе работы приложения? Тогда это было бы легче.

Comment: Извините, а чем отличаются тогда ваши `тулбары` друг от друга?

Comment: Пунктами меню, заголовком, цветом. Проблемы из-за первого.

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Благодарю, думаю: то, что нужно. Вечером проверю.

Comment: Сделал проще: в onCreateOptionsMenu создал переключатель фрагмента, который на экране в данный момент и использовал методы menu.add, menu.removeItem и другие.